# How to change different div background img when hovering an empty div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hope you can help and that this can be done...

I have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/keG6G/5/

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="logo">
     <div id="drop1">
     </div>

     <div class="clear"></div>

     <div id="drop2">
     </div>

     <div id="drop3">
     </div>
</div>

<div id="words">
    <div id="a">
    </div>

    <div id="b">
    </div>

    <div id="c">
    </div>
</div>
```

`<div id="logo">` has just a background image.

`<div id="drop1">`, `<div id="drop2">` and `<div id="drop2">` are transparent (showing border to make them visible).

`div`'s 'a', 'b' and 'c' have background image.

What I need to do is this: when hovering 'drop1', 'drop2' or 'drop3' div, the background img of div'logo' will change together with background img of div 'a', 'b' and 'c'.

So just to be more clear, if I hover `div'drop1'`: `div'logo'`, `div'a'`, `div'b'` and `div'c'` will change background image.

I'm not sure if its best using jQuery once I don't know much about it.

I hope that I managed to explain my issue well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following jquery code

```
$('#drop1,#drop2,#drop3').hover(
  function(){
    $('#a').css({"background-color":"blue"});
    $('#b').css({"background-color":"red"});
    $('#c').css({"background-color":"green"});
    $('#logo').css({"background-color":"black"});
  },function(){
    //similarly give them their original backgrounds
});
```

If you want to change their backgrounds to a common one then make a class new_background and then add

```
$('#a,#b,#c,#logo').addClass("new_background");
```

Comment: wow that seems pretty easy :) thanks! and in the second function there is an easy way to bring everything back as original when you dont hover none of the div? instead of re assigning the original backgrounds one by one

Comment: just an other question... does this code have problems with some browsers versions?

Comment: Take a look at jQuery's page for browser support 

http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: And if you have a common background for all the divs then use addClass () and removeClass(), that way it'd be much more easier